# Get Json response from an Intent action view(browser) Android

Tags: android, android-intent

My app launches an Intent to open a website. In the website browser you can write your username and your password and then you log in. Once you are logged in, the website returns some data in JSON format.

I know how to read a JSON from a URL, but I don't know how to get the JSON in my app once you are in the website(Intent) logged in.

Comment: Did you use JSONObject ?

Answer (score 0):

**JSONObject structure = Utilities.getJSONFromUrl(url);

JsonObject subcat=struct.getJSONArray("subcategories").getJSONOBJECT(0);

JSONObject innersubcats = subcat.getJSONArray("subcategories").getJSONOBJECT(0);

String id = innersubcats.getstring("id");

log.i("ID OF Inner Subcategories",id);**

Read this...u can use getstring for get data from JSON string to your appplication ..

try to implement it in your application

Comment: The point is that I don't know the url where the Json is located. First i have to log in to the website through the intent action view, and then he returns me the url of the json.

Comment: user2139553:::hey http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=SrBachchan u will get directly json string..here i give u one json string u can apply it......we have to find the json string...we can not get it easily....

Comment: @Arià how did you resolve the issue. Please update. Thanks

Comment: @OluwatobiAdenekan It was a few years ago, I don't really remember how I solved it. Sorry...